# How to convert a mysql query in CakePHP pagination condition

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I have below `MySQL` query.
I just want to convert a MySQL query in CakePHP pagination condition. So that i can get result.

**MySql Query:**

```
SELECT *, 3963 * acos(cos(radians(90-lat ))*cos(radians(90-'".$result['lat']."'))".
"+sin(radians(90-lat ))* sin(radians(90-'".$result['lat']."'))".
"*cos(radians(lng- '".$result['lng']."'))) AS distance FROM member"." HAVING (distance < 5) ORDER BY distance ASC
```

**i am using this PHP Code**

```
$condition = array('Member.is_deleted !=' => 1, 'Member.status !='  => 0, 'OR' => array());


$this->paginate = array(
                    'conditions' => $condition,
                    'fields' => array()                 
                );
```

Comment: It is not clear where do you want to "put" that query. Give an example of query you want to get from Paginator.

Comment: i want to convert a MySQL query in CakePHP pagination condition.

Comment: Make your distance calculation into a virtual field.

Comment: DUDE , `$condition = array('Member.is_deleted !=' => 1, 'Member.status !='  => 0, 'OR' => array());`

Where is this condition in YOUR SQL QUERY?